# How to set the env['SERVER_NAME'] in rack/test?

Tags: ruby, rspec, sinatra, rack, webmock

In Sinatra tests, `env['SERVER_NAME']` defaults to `www.example.com`. How can I set this to some arbitrary domain?

Capybara has `.default_host` method, but not using Capybara.

Or, is it possible to change the env[`DEFAULT_HOST`]?

Using RSpec, Sinatra, WebMock.

EDIT: Adding `env['SERVER_NAME'] = 'www.foo.com'` to RSpec test raises exception:

`NameError:      undefined local variable or method 'env' for #<RSpec::Core::ExampleGroup::Nested_1::Nested_1:0x007fe6ce3b5ff8>`

Comment: `env['SERVER_NAME'] = 'mything.com'`?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The `env` helper is only accessible within a Sinatra app.

One way to change it is when making a request:

```
get "/blah", {}, {'HTTP_SERVER_NAME' => 'www.foo.com' }
```

The 3rd argument of a rack/test `get` or `post` is the headers hash.